# How to generate an Authenticode Hash in C#?

Tags: c#, hash

I am looking into the feasibility of generating XML files that can be imported into AppLocker. According to the post I have seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/882648/why-are-the-sha256-hashes-used-by-applocker-different-to-other-generators), AppLocker generates a SHA2 Authenticode hash despite it showing SHA256 as being the hash type.

I have been looking at the hash algorithms available in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace, but I cannot find one for a SHA2 Authenticode. Is this possible to do in .NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256`

Here is MSDN article about SHA256 Class and there is example how to use it [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx)