# Generating Windows AppLocker SHA256 Authenticode - PE256

Tags: c++, windows, applocker

I am trying to generate App Locker rules programmatically.As MSDN described [it uses SHA2 Authenticode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/use-applocker-and-software-restriction-policies-in-the-same-domain).

I have tried using SHA256 Class from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901211/7570485) but it only generates SHA256 and not Authenticode.

For example Notepad++.exe

```
SHA256 - 02f2cee4118a8f8d732d736e1758a38abdceea6470ba63ea224ae56b27e4983c
SRPv2 data (AppLocker) - cd068ebc869a1c7dee0ea1d5e19e89d0cacb8af385d44b0f3a57b5aefcf3c051
```

Edit: With a little more research, I found that Windows AppLocker expects PE256 hash.

Comment: SHA2 is a different hashing algorithm from SHA256. The same input will give very different output.  You need to use an implementation  of SHA2.

Comment: I have tried SHA256 and SHA512/256. It did not yield correct result.

Comment: run PowerScript and gather result from text file: `Get-AppLockerFileInformation c:\tools\calchashcmd.exe | Format-List > result.txt` :)

Comment: @Xnkr did you get answer to this question? Is there any programmatic way instead of using PowerShell?